# How can I change my language/keyboard input language system-wide temporarily?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, input-languages

I currently have two languages set up; English and Dutch. The only difference is in keyboard input. The Dutch one uses the French/Belgian AZERTY layout and the English one uses the Irish/English QWERTY layout (`@` = `Shift`+`'`).

When a Belgian colleague needs to use my computer, I switch the language to NL (Dutch) (therefore the input to AZERTY) using the language bar, but it seems to be application-specific. (I.e: After changing the input to AZERTY for my colleague, if he then clicks on another program it switches back to QWERTY for that program).

#### Is there a way I can quickly switch between the two comprehensively yet temporarily?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you already set up two different keyboard layouts, you can also turn on "Switch between input languages".

In Windows XP go to:
Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Languages tab > Details button > Settings tab > Key Settings > Switch between input languages.

This should enable you to quickly change the language/keyboard layout when you press the e.g. Left Alt+Shift combination on your keyboard. This only has sense if you installed two or more languages/keyboard layouts.

Second approach could be considering giving your friend a different windows profile on your PC. That way both of you can use your own separate settings and use same applications on same computer. For this solution switching required log off/log on.

Hope this helps to resolve your problem.

Comment: Nope. This is still **application-specific**. Nice shortcut though.

Comment: So far I haven't seen any other solutions to this problem other than having only one keyboard layout/language installed on the system, which I doubt is what you wanted in the first place :)

Comment: I personally would prefer just QWERTY but for colleagues to pair program (etc) with me on my computer, and vice versa, we need a good solution to this.

Comment: Got it :) and edited answer :)

Comment: So you're suggesting that when he wants to type on my computer, that I log out and into that new account? That's too much trouble. Remember now, I'm saying pressing `(left) Alt`+`Shift` on every application he wants to use is too much trouble. We could be programming together for example, switching who types every few minutes.

Comment: So basically you are asking for a technical solution for an operational problem ? :) If you are writing code, pressing Alt+Shift is 2 keystrokes before typing other keys on the keyboard. It shouldn't be much of a problem when you train yourself to do that. Try it, it is really easy once you get used to it :)

Comment: Sure. It's what I was doing already but with a shortcut instead of two clicks. But I asked the question to find a system-wide (not application-specific) solution specifically, as it states, so this doesn't really answer it unfortunately.

Comment: I haven't found any for Windows XP and not sure it exists. App-specific behavior you mentioned is actually a feature of Windows XP and is tied to user settings, which in your case is two users so... kind of an impossible scenario without modifying users or changing the settings for every app. :) Cheers! :)

Comment: Oh really? ["Feature"](http://globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/bug_vs_feature.gif). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: +1 for making me laugh with the image and completely ignoring rest of the comment :)

Comment: Seriously, I understand the "feature" as you describe it, but who wants app-specific input language settings? Seems like a feature *cough* bug to me. Thanks for taking the effort to write all this:)